# MEF ObjectBuilder for NServiceBus

Tags: mef, nservicebus

Does an MEF ObjectBuilder exist for NServiceBus at the moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this thread where Chris Ortman attached an ObjectBuilder for MEF:

[nservicebus-mef-support](http://tech.dir.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/7802)

Comment: There is a zip file attached on the post linked above.  The github link is 404.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the current list, and MEF is not one of them:

- AutoFac
- Castle Windsor
- Spring
- StructureMap
- Unity
- Ninject - this came through very recently